# Fetching document using SelfLink vs routing using user-defined Ids - request charge

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am testing `RequestCharge` for 2 approaches for fetchng documents from DocumentDB.

**Using user generated ids (`id` property on Document)**

`var feedResponse = await this._client.ReadDocumentAsync<MyCRLType>("dbs/myDatabaseName/colls/MyCollectionName/docs/myUserGeneratedId");`

**Using `selfLink` as provided by documentDB:**

`var feedResponse = await this._client.ReadDocumentAsync<MyCRLType>("dbs/abc==/colls/def=/docs/CAUsAO7sWgABAAAAAAAAAA==/");`

For both cases, `feedResponse.RequestCharge` returns 1.

I would like someone from DocumentDB team to confirm if this is guaranteed behavior that these 2 ways of accessing documents always have same RequestCharge?
I can't find anything about it in docs and i could imagine user-defined Ids way to be somewhat more expensive.

Could someone clarify if this is guaranteed or just coincidence in my tests so far?

Comment: Based on my experience, both will return same RU charges.  I